# Convert void* to double

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads, type-conversion

I am attempting to use the `pthread` library to calculate `n` fibonacci numbers where `n` can be from range `0-1000`. I am running in to a weird error when I try to typecast my `void*` to a `double`.

In my main here is my call to my calculate fibonacci function:

```
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, calc_fib, (void *)n);
```

In my `calc_fib` function I am attempting to typecast with:

```
void *calc_fib( void *num)
{
    double n;
    n = (double)num;
    ...
```

However, when I attempt to do this I get the following errors:

```
In function ‘calc_fib’:
error: pointer value used where a floating point value was expected
In function ‘main’:
error: cannot convert to a pointer type
```

Am I not able to typecast from `void*` to `double` in C or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`void *num` is a pointer. `double n` is a variable.

You can cast `void*` to `double*`:

```
double *p = (double *)num;
```

Then you dereference it:

```
double n = *p;
```

Or in one line:

```
double n = *(double *)num;
```

Comment: Yep that was it exactly. I always forget about the subtleties of casting between different pointer types.

Answer (score 3):

First you want to convert the void* to a double*. Then you need to dereference the pointer to assign it to a double.

```
void *calc_fib( void *num)
{
    double n;
    n = *(double*)num;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't portably cast the `double` to a pointer - for a start, the pointer type may not have enough bits.

If  `n` won't be changed in `main` after calling `pthread_create`, you can pass a pointer to the `n` variable in `main` itself (i.e. `(void*)&n`, then use `*(double*)num` inside `calc_fib`).

If `n` might change - perhaps you've a loop calculating a variety of n values to pass to different threads you spawn - then you must avoid a race condition where the new thread might not have read the value before the main thread replaces it.  You could use a mutex for this - it means there's a fixed amount of memory needed independent of the number of threads - but the code's relatively verbose and it further serialises and slows down the launching of the threads.  A typically better approach is to put each value into a separate memory address.  You could use an array with as many values as you'll have new threads, or allocate memory on the heap for each `double` then let the threads read then release that memory....