# Casting a void * to a double segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

I found the following answer: [Convert void* to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700384/convert-void-to-double/12700414#12700414)

However, I am getting segmetation fault. Why is that?

Code:

```
void * p = (void *) 1234;
double n = *(double *)p;
```

Comment: A segmentation fault seems perfectly reasonable for the code you are showing. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: The answer you're referencing is talking about converting a `(void*)` that was *already* a legal pointer known to be pointing to memory containing a `double`. You just made a garbage pointer to almost certainly unallocated memory. The two are unrelated.

Comment: @teapot418 I don't understand why you have to be so mean. I just followed the example and it didn't work. My question is perfectly reasonable for a beginner.

Comment: It was not my intention to be mean. I genuinely wanted to know what you wanted to achieve (display the address of a pointer? if I see correctly). The question seems somewhat [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Adding detail about your goals can help untangle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer `p` is assigned to address 1234 that you chose at *random?*. You are then referencing a *random* address. It does not correspond to a valid allocated chunk of memory.

Comment: Well, I am trying to deal wih very large (void *) pointers. In my school's tests there are very large numbers also chosen at random. I have to display their value without using printf.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you found assumes that you have a `void*` which actually points to a double, e.g.

```
double original = 3.0;
void* p = (void*) &original;
```

Your `void*` points to a pretty random bit of memory.

Answer (score 0):

The `num` in the code in the page you link to is a pointer, not some arbitrary integer value. It is declared `void *num`, and the code in the accepted answer converts it from one type of pointer (`void *`) to another type of pointer (`int *`).

You are attempting to convert an arbitrary integer to a pointer. Unless that integer is the address of something in your process’ memory space, in the format used by your C implementation’s integer-to-pointer conversion, you should not expect converting it to a pointer to produce a useful pointer.

Virtual memory spaces are huge today, and a simple program uses only a tiny fraction of the space, so most of the addresses are not mapped to actual memory, and attempting to use them results in segment fault or similar error.

In particular, the first page (commonly 4096 bytes) of memory maybe deliberately unused so that attempting to access address 0 gets a fault. This causes programs that incorrectly use a null pointer (due to a bug) to get a fault instead of using incorrect data from that address. This is preferred because it reveals the bug sooner. Since 1234 is within the first page, it is not mapped to valid memory.